# How to get current gcloud user name from golang executable?

Tags: go, gcloud

I am trying to implement the below gcloud command in Go Lang.

```
>gcloud config get-value account
abc@def.com
```

I have looked in "https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go", but I am unable to find how I could implement this.

Any suggestions for libraries\code that I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significant time investment into researching this, there are no options as of Jan 2019. Best course of action is

```
gcloud config config-helper --format json
```